# React + Redux Simple Router : cannot find listen of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router-redux

I've been trying to setup `react` + `react-router` + `redux` + `redux-simple-router` with no success. Everything seems to work fine until I add `redux-simple-router` to the mix, after which I get

`"[TypeError: Cannot read property 'listen' of undefined]` even though I am passing in BrowserHistory Object.

Here's the code -

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Route, Router, BrowserHistory } from 'react-router';
import HashHistory from 'react-router/lib/HashHistory';
import { compose, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { syncHistory, routeReducer } from 'redux-simple-router'
import * as reducers from 'reducers/reducers'

import Blank from 'routes/blank';

export default (withHistory, onUpdate) => {


const reducer = combineReducers(Object.assign({}, reducers, {
  routing: routeReducer
}));

const reduxRouterMiddleware = syncHistory(BrowserHistory)
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(reduxRouterMiddleware)(createStore)

const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducer)

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={BrowserHistory} onUpdate={onUpdate}>
        <Route path='/' component={Blank} />
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

**Note:** I just discovered I'm compiling react templates in a express server using `renderToString()`. Is that why its not defined?? What do i do?

**Note 2:** if I instead `import BrowserHistory from 'react-router/lib/BrowserHistory'` then I get

`TypeError: history.listen is not a function`;

Comment: have you tried `browserHistory` instead of `BrowserHistory` ?

Comment: @Road I'm importing `BrowserHistory` from the router.. why `browserHistory`?

Comment: because `react-router` is exporting it as `browserHistory` and I think it is case sensitive https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/modules/index.js#L28

Comment: @Road i tried it, same thing.. see note #2 I added..

Comment: are you doing this server or client side?

Comment: I am getting the same error. I have a universally rendered React app, I've followed the directions to the letter and I get: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'listen' of undefined`. This is on the react-router-redux package, which is the new name for this repo. I have my store in a separate file, it's unreasonable (at this time) for me to create the store in this file. I don't know if that could have anything to do with it. Very baffled with this one.

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same error. I got it by following the tutorial here: https://github.com/rackt/redux-simple-router/blob/e1df260888d1032d1e68c7694a06b457a4f0130f/README.md

Then I realised above it stood this message:

> Note: This example uses react-router's 2.0 API, which is currently
>   released under version 2.0.0-rc5.

[Upgrading](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) my packages like this:

```
 history       ^1.17.0  →  ^2.0.0-rc2
 react-router   ^1.0.3  →  ^2.0.0-rc5
```

... resolved the error.